# In C++, What's the difference between char array's name and a char pointer?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is array name a pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

```
char arr[1024];
arr++ //move arr to arr+1, error!
```

I have heard the the name of a char array is a char pointer, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of an array decays to an pointer to its first element sometimes.
An expression with array type will convert to a pointer anytime an array type is not legal, but a pointer type is.

You cannot do:

```
arr++;
```

Because array is an non modifiable l-value.

Comment: sometimes, we can use array name as a pointer (e.g. if a function need a pointer), is this a decay? when we can decay? is there a rule?

Comment: @lovespring: I stated the rule in my answer. *An expression with array type (which could be an array name) will convert to a pointer anytime an array type is not legal, but a pointer type is.*  Example is: Declaration of an array as a function parameter is converted into a declaration of a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

An array is a **block of memory** to which you **gave a name**.

What does it mean to "increment" it by one? That doesn't make any sense.

A pointer is a **memory address**. "Incrementing" it by one means to make it point to the element after it.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays and pointers are not always exchangeable.  A more interesting example to illustrate the difference between arrays and pointers is a 2D array:

Consider `int **a` and `int b[3][3]`.

In the first approach to a 2D array we have a 1D array of pointers to 1D arrays in memory (of course you have to allocate the memory dynamically to use this).

In the second approach of actually using a 2D C array, we have the elements laid out sequentially in memory, and there's no separate location where an array of pointers are stored.

If you try to dereference `b`, you get a pointer to its first element (i.e. `b` gets converted to an `int (*)[3]` type).

Answer (score 0):

nothing, apart from looks..

Well and as you defined the array there you declared already 1024 bytes for the array. Also you obviously can't change the array "base".

Answer (score 0):

An array name is for most (but not all) purposes identical to a constant pointer (not to be confused with a pointer to a constant).  Because it's a constant, you cannot modify it with the increment operator `++`.  There's a good answer explaining this in more detail in [an older similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c).